# Divide data frame by deciles and compute mean and median for each decile R

Tags: r

Given the following structure of data, I would like to divide the "Category"s in deciles for each year given by "value" and calculate for every year and every decile the mean and median for the variable "value".

```
df <- data.frame(Category = rep(LETTERS[1:15], each = 6),
                 Year = rep(2010:2015, 15),
                 value = runif(90, 50, 100))
```

I have tried this but then I have problem calculating the mean and mediam in each year for each decile (not sure this is 100% correct though).

```
a <- df %>%
  mutate(quantile = ntile(value, 10))
```

I would like to get a dataframe by year and deciles with the mean and mediam of each decile in each year

For dividing the df in deciles I have tried this which apparently gives me a result (not sure if 100% correct)

```
a <- df %>%
  mutate(quantile = ntile(value, 10))
```

For the calculation of the mean I have tried two methods and both fail:

using data.frame

```
w <- setDT(a)[, Mean := mean(value), by = .(Year, quantile)][]
```

and using dplry

```
z <- a %>% group_by(Year,quantile) %>% summarise (x = mean(value))
```

What I am looking for as a result is a data frame with one row per year and decile and their mean and mediam values.

Comment: It is not clear to me why `w` and `z` are not correct.

Comment: Perhaps you want `df %>% group_by(Year) %>% mutate(decile = ntile(value, 10)) %>% group_by(Year, decile) %>% summarise(mean = mean(value), median = median(value))`.

Comment: thanks @Axeman, but his doesn't really work. I need the mean and median of each decile for every year

Comment: _"I need the mean and median of each decile for every year"_: Yes, that is what my code gives. It is not clear to me why your own solution or my solution are not correct. You need to be explicit and explain what about these solutions is not what you want.

Comment: your solution only gives me one median and one mean.

I want something like this with corresponding values for mean and median (and all the way to 10 deciles):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYQVQ.png

Comment: Yes, this is what my code does. 6 years, 10 deciles, so 60 rows. Did you run it?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code

### code

```r
library(tidyverse)

# create a df with row numbers
df2 <- df %>% arrange(Year) %>% mutate(row=row_number())

# create a dfs with decile
dfs <- data.frame(row=seq(1, nrow(df), 10)) %>% mutate(decile=row_number())

# merge the df2 with dfs by row number and then derive the mean and median
df3 <- df2 %>% left_join(dfs, by='row') %>% fill(decile) %>% 
group_by(Year, decile) %>% mutate(mean=mean(value), median=median(value))
```

### output

```r
# A tibble: 90 × 7
# Groups:   Year, decile [12]
   Category  Year value   row decile  mean median
   <chr>    <int> <dbl> <dbl>  <int> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 A         2010  70.4     1      1  80.2   78.7
 2 B         2010  88.6     2      1  80.2   78.7
 3 C         2010  63.3     3      1  80.2   78.7
 4 D         2010  71.6     4      1  80.2   78.7
 5 E         2010  88.1     5      1  80.2   78.7
 6 F         2010  97.4     6      1  80.2   78.7
 7 G         2010  88.9     7      1  80.2   78.7
 8 H         2010  76.6     8      1  80.2   78.7
 9 I         2010  78.8     9      1  80.2   78.7
10 J         2010  78.6    10      1  80.2   78.7
# … with 80 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: Hi thank you. But I need a final result with the mean and median of each decile for each year. So for each year there would be 10 rows (ten means and medians). The final table result should be 60 x 4

Comment: could you please confirm if it is the updated output

Comment: there are 15 rows for 2010, how we can get 10 rows for 2010, we need to consider all the 15 rows for 2010 with values for the mean and median, right?

Comment: yes, you are right. But what I meant is that the info I want in the result is just year, decile, mean and median, since for all categories of the same decile the mean and median are the same.

Comment: @jakatam I get the following error: `Error in `n()`:
! Must be used inside dplyr verbs.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.`